# Removing empty values in a nested objects using react-hook-form

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, react-hook-form, nested-object

Question:
Hi,
Currently, I have a react hook form set up where user should be able to remove each tag inside the array of nested groups. I was able to have each tag removed from the list, but I wasn't able to figure out ways to remove the empty subgroup.

Is there a way to handle removing empty subgroup in the nested objects using react-hook-form?

CSB link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-hook-form-lb57qc?file=%2Fsrc%2FForm%2Fconstant.ts%3A25%2C29

Expected Behavior:

[image]

[image]